# How to define a function inside haskell newtype?

Tags: haskell, newtype, type-signature

I am trying to decipher the record syntax in haskell for newtype and my understanding breaks when there is a function inside newtype. Consider this simple example

```
newtype C a b = C { getC :: (a -> b) -> a }
```

As per my reasoning C is a type which accepts a function and a parameter in it's constructor.
so,

```
let d1 = C $ (2 *) 3
```

`:t d1` also gives

```
d1 :: Num ((a -> b) -> a) => C a b
```

Again to check this I do `:t getC d1`, which shows this

```
getC d1 :: Num ((a -> b) -> a) => (a -> b) -> a
```

Why the error if I try `getC d1`? `getC` should return the function and it's parameter or at least apply the parameter.

I can't have `newtype C a b = C { getC :: (a->b)->b } deriving (Show)`, because this won't make sense!

Answer (score 4):

It's always good to emphasise that Haskell has two completely separate namespaces, the *type language* and the *value language*. In your case, there's

- A type constructor `C :: Type -> Type -> Type`, which lives in the type language. It takes two types `a`, `b` (of kind `Type`) and maps them to a type `C a b` (also of kind `Type`)<sup>†</sup>.
- A value constructor `C :: ((a->b) -> a) -> C a b`, which lives in the value language. It takes a function `f` (of type `(a->b) -> a`) and maps it to a value `C f` (of type `C a b`).

Perhaps it would be less confusing if you had

```
newtype CT a b = CV ((a->b) -> a)
```

but because for a newtype there is always exactly one value constructor (and exactly one type constructor) it makes sense to name them the same.

`CV` is a value constructor that accepts one function, full stop. That function will have signature `(a->b) -> a`, i.e. its argument is also a function, but as far as `CT` is concerned this doesn't really matter.

Really, it's kind of wrong that `data` and `newtype` declarations use a `=` symbol, because it doesn't mean the things on the left and right are “the same” – can't, because they don't even belong to the same language. There's an alternative syntax which expresses the relation better:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Kind

data CT :: Type -> Type -> Type where
   CV :: ((a->b) -> a) -> CT a b
```

As for that value you tried to construct

> `let d1 = CV $ (\x->(2*x)) 3`

here you did *not* pass “a function and a parameter” to `CV`. What you actually did<sup>‡</sup> was, you applied the function `\x->2*x` to the value `3` (might as well have written `6`) and passed that number to `CV`. But as I said, `CV` expects a function. What then happens is, GHC tries to interpret `6` as a function, which gives the bogus constraint `Num ((a->b) -> a)`. What that means is: “if `(a->b)->a` is a number type, then...”. Of course it *isn't* a number type, [so the rest doesn't make sense either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>It may seem redundant to talk of “types of kind `Type`”. Actually, when talking about “types” we often mean “entities in the type-level language”. These have kinds (“type-level types”) of which `Type` (the kind of <sub><sup>(*lifted*)</sup></sub> value-level values) is the most prominent, but not the only one – you can also have type-level numbers and type-level functions – `C` is indeed one.
Note that `Type` was historically written `*`, but this notation is deprecated because it's inconsistent (confusion with multiplication operator).</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>This is because `$` has the lowest precedence, i.e. the expression `CV $ (\x->(2*x)) 3` is actually parsed as `CV ((\x->(2*x)) 3)`, or equivalently `let y = 2*3 in CV y`.</sub>

Comment: So how do you explain this,  A Haskell continuation has the following type:

newtype Cont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }

A continuation takes a function of type (a -> r) and generates an r, where r can sometimes be a fixed value like Int or IO ().

Comment: It means this: _A Haskell continuation `c` has a type of the following form: `c :: (A -> R) -> R`, for instance it might be `c :: (String -> Int) -> Int`. To abstract over this, we define the wrapper `newtype Cont r a = ...`, so that we can then simply write `c' :: Cont String Int`, defined by `c' = Cont c`._

Comment: Ok let's follow with your definition that ((a->b) -> a) is a function that's required in value constructor of C. How do I now initialize C? Let's say I define a function                                                                                                                  let f a = 2*a which can act as parameter to C's value constructor. I am a bit lost with defining C using this function f. Should it be C (\x e -> x e), where x is the function and e is the parameter and I am calling the function on this parameter e.

Comment: If Cont is defined in newtype shouldn't it be newtype Cont r a = Cont {runCont :: ((a->r) -> r) }, a function which accepts a function as parameter?

Comment: So can I say this a continuation is a function which takes a function of type (a->r) and generates an r?

Comment: Ok, well... I think we're gonna need some nomenclature nitpicking here. “`((a->b) -> a)` is a function...” no. That is a _type_. “...define a function `let f a = 2*a`...” alright, `f` _is_ a function. Unfortunately, it has a type `n -> n` (it maps a number to a number), could be `Int -> Int` for instance. This doesn't match with the type you need. What you could use instead is, for instance, `g :: (Int -> Bool) -> Int`, defined by `g f = if f 1 then 1 else 2`.

Comment: Well, it _is_ a confusing subject. And perhaps you should have chosen something easier to start with Haskell... Even after 5 years of Haskell (and plenty of contravariant endofunctors in bicartesian closed categories), _continuations_ are a concept that I never quite grokked. — Did you read some easier example of newtypes, along the lines `newtype Time = Time { getSeconds :: Double }`?

Answer (score 3):

> As per my reasoning C is a type which accepts a function and a parameter

How so? The constructor has only one argument.
Newtypes always have a single constructor with exactly one argument.

The type C, otoh, has two type parameters. But that has nothing to do with the number of arguments you can apply to the constructor.